# C# mocked property has value in Debugger but causes null reference

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, dbcontext

Why might this be the case?:

- hovering over the container class (`DbContext`) shows that the Persons property has a value (`Castle.Proxies.`) and the `Results View` shows a List with an item in (as expected).
- hovering over the property when referenced shows NULL and referencing property causes `NullReferenceException`

**The Container Class is `BrokerContext`**

```
public interface IBrokerContext : IDisposable
        {
            DbSet<Agents> Agents { get; set; }
            
            IDbContextTransactionProxy BeginTransaction();
        }

        public class BrokerContext : ApplicationDbContext, IBrokerContext
        {
            public new DbSet<Agents> Agents { get; set; }
      ...
     }
```

The purpose of BrokerContext is to be a proxy/adapter for the ApplicationDbContext so that I can mock `BeginTransaction()`.

My code uses a `_db` of type `ApplicationDbContext` which has the Sets declared in BrokerContext. In my test, **I am trying to construct a mock of type BrokerContext and pass that object into the class being tested to override the ApplicationDbContex**t. That way I can control what happens when `BeginTransaction()` is called.

However, despite doing this:

```
mockDb.Object.Agents = mockAgentSet.Object;
```

And passing that mock object into my class being tested, and seeing the property _db.Agents has a value in the debug view: any reference to `await _db.Agents` returns null!

**The DbContext being overriden:**

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public virtual DbSet<Agents> Agents { get; set; }
...
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of fact, that BrokerContext has two different 'Agents' fields due to 'new' keyword? One as 'ApplicationDbContext' and another as 'BrokerContext'? Why do you need 'new' keyword for 'Agents' field in 'BrokerContext' ?

Comment: @Quercus thanks for comment. I tried the new keyword as a last-ditch attempt to fix. I just double checked and the same thing happens when using no keyword or trying the "override" keyword. Same happens if the parent class's properties are not virtual

Comment: Ok, assuming that mockDb is a `Mock<BrokerContext>`. Probably Moq itself creates two different `Agents` in mock object - one to implement `IBrokerContext` and another as override of `ApplicationDbContext` property. Try to remove `Agents` from `BrokerContext` at all and set Agents in test as: `((ApplicationDbContext)mockDb.Object).Agents = mockAgentSet.Object;`

Comment: @Quercus I forgot to say, you led me in the right direction and I was able to resolve :) can you put into a Answer so I can accept it?

Comment: p.s. fix was to remove the references to the properties in the mock classes (Removed from BrokerContext) so the only DbSet is the one in the class being overriden